# Twitter app with pic.twitter.com upload

Tags: twitter

The [official Twitter app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twitter.android) uses an external service for image upload instead of its own image service. I want a app which uses the official twitter image upload service. The reason is that I don't want to show my uploaded images the whole world.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know any too **:/**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Twicca](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.r246.twicca&hl=en) with the plugin "Multi Image".

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the app defaults to the official service.